# How to store context in singleton kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a SDK build up

I have singleton class to initialise it from where I am taking context as parameter to function.

I want to store this in some variable as I will be using the context object thorughout the application lifetime.

If I store it in variable I get the following warning

```
Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak
```

This is my class

```
object Sdk {
private var context: Context? = null
fun init(context: Context) {
    this.context = context
}
}
```

What other alternative can be there to store?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `companion object` in Application Class

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    companion object {
        lateinit var context: Application
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        context= this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to store your context. If u are in a view you have access to it. You can also pass it through a method as a parameter or get your ApplicationContext, but you should avoid to store it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a context factory which can be used across multiple modules of the same app.

```
object ContextFactory {

   private val context: Context? = null

   fun setAppContext(context: Context) {
      this.context = context
   }

   fun getAppContext(): Context = context ?: throw IllegalStateException("Context is not provided")

}
```

In your app's class that extends `Application`

```
class MyApp : Application {

   override fun onCreate() {
      ContextFactory.setAppContext(this)
   }
}
```